# Django 4.2.5 System check identified no issues (0 silenced)

Tags: python, django

After reinstalled my app on another computer
Want to change Python Version and update if necessary Librairies
Eveything is ok for now (I had some issue with xhtmltopdf librairies with python 3.10 and more so for now I'm using 3.9 Python version)
I run manage.py runserver ... But I've only got this message

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

I tried to run with **-v manage.py** to have some details .. Nothing wrong on details

I see some user who have this kind of issue and modify the 3306 port for mysql ... I did but still the same message.

Is there any other solution ?

[EDIT]
For more information, my DB on mysql is installed on the same computer than my code. No VPN, no Proxy ... just localhost or ComputerName.
I change the port to 3307 ... NOthing change
I saw a connection into MysqlWorkbench when i launch runserver in PyCharm ... but still same message ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the problem with the message? It simply says it ran some checks, and everything is ok. You can omit that message, but it does not make much difference.

Comment: Usually when i run python manage.py runserver ... after perform check it shows details that server is running and url 127.0.0.1:8000 is available
No message except the one I showed and when I tried to go to localhost:8000 on my browser no website appear...

Comment: likely because it is still trying to get a connection with the database, but the database does not respond (or is behind a VPN or anything), this will let the server wait for response, until eventually the connection will timeout.

Comment: When I see in MysqlWorkbench I see the connection when server is launched :
'-- Connection Id: 51
-- User: Odissine
-- Host: localhost
-- DB: lapetitepepiniere
-- Command: Sleep
-- Time: 3
-- State: None'
But still the same message in python console ... My Mysql DB is install on the same PC as my Apps where i run server ... full localy ;)

Comment: but the point is that the connection will *timeout* because the database does not answer, or likely can not be reached (for example after a VPN), so the connection procedure is still "working" or at least waiting for answer. Eventually it will time out, and raise the error.

Comment: if the database would respond that the credentials are bad for example, it would stop the connection and report that, but it is still waiting for answers.

Comment: It's the same credentials as I used in DBeaver to connect on , in DBEaver it's working

Comment: but the database likely never *gets* the request, if it is for example behind a VPN, the connection will never hit the database...